# How to retrieve the value of a QML property from C++?

Tags: qt, qml, qquickitem

I have the following `QQuickItem` defined in `main.qml`.

```
Flickable {
  id: my_quick
  Accessible.name: "my_quick_item_name"
  objectName: "myquickitem"
  enabled: true

  property real quickProperty: 1.0
}
```

I get `my_quick` object in the following way on **C++ side**.

```
QQuickItem * my_quick_ptr = QmlEngine_Ptr->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("myquickitem");
```

**How** can I get the current value of `quickProperty` set, into C++ side using `my_quick_ptr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean QML properties, you can use this approach:

`QQmlProperty::read(my_quick_ptr, "quickProperty").toReal()`

Using `QObject`'s facilities should also work for QML properties:

`my_quick_ptr->property("quickProperty").toReal()`

Also, `findChild` returns a `QObject`, so you will need to do a safe cast to get a derived pointer from it:

```
QQuickItem * my_quick_ptr = qobject_cast<QQuickItem *>(QmlEngine_Ptr->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("myquickitem"));
if (my_quick_ptr) // successfully found and cast, can be safely used
```

Comment: thanks, can you pls make your answer inline with the sample code in my question? I am using a `qreal` with objectName as `myquickitem` & the property name is `quickProperty`

Comment: @dtech, on Qt 6.2.0 I get this warning "Don't call QList::operator[]() on temporary [clazy-detaching-temporary]" on the `qobject_cast` line.